# How can I generalize this code in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code that I want to generalize in Python, and all I want is to seperate this output to send each line in a unique mail.

Thank you in advance,

Here's my code.

```
    art = [[600, 'pet', 'small'], [300, 'pet', 'medium'], [600, 'pet', 'medium'], [200, 'pet', 'big'], [300, 'pet', 'big'], [200, 'pet', 'small'], [600, 'pet', 'big']]

    art_600 =[]
    art_300 =[]
    art_200 =[]

    for i in range(len(art)):
        if art[0][0] == art[i][0]:
            art_600.append(art[i])
        if art[1][0] == art[i][0]:
            art_300.append(art[i])
        if art[-2][0] == art[i][0]:
            art_200.append(art[i])

    print(art_600)
    print(art_300)
    print(art_200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make dict and iterate through

```
for key in dict_:
    # do your code
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrey, I will test this idea.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).